# Desperately Looking for a tikZ MWE

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs, bar-chart, coordinates

I'm looking for a basic MWE on how to create a tikZ graph (or any other environment) along the lines of the attached picture.
I'm able to create one simple coords system but that's about it...
What's really bugging me is that it doesn't look very complicated but I ran out of ideas...
[image: Example Graph]

Thanks folks!

Comment: Welcome to Te.SX. The tikz manual is full of examples.

Comment: I know, but I don't really know what exactly to look for and also didn't find anything helping remotely by scrolling through...

Comment: This can be build using `rectangle` and normal lines. The hardest thing are the hatched rectangles, but you should be able to find a fill pattern that looks like this with a quick search on the internet. So you'll need `\draw`, `rectangle`, `\draw[fill=gray]`, `\node` and `pattern`, and for the dashed arrows `\draw[->,dashed]`.

Comment: Hmm, for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436259/timeline-in-latex/436304 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302088/customizable-timeline https://www.google.com/search?hs=9gm&channel=fs&sxsrf=ACYBGNS6JkZcd-UFyyH7uk8sbqtVOUKCsQ:1574013395568&q=tikz+timelines&tbm=isch&source=univ&client=ubuntu&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjh3cHq6PHlAhXWA2MBHX_DCyUQsAR6BAgGEAE&biw=1099&bih=653

Comment: Are you aware of the `pgfgantt` package? Your screen shot resembles very much a Gantt chart, so maybe this is what you need.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat yes, tank you, I tried 'pgfgantt' and it's what I use in the meantime, but for some reason I'd love to be able to exactly recreate the picture...

Comment: @fjungplan It is straightforward but tedious so people here are happy to help you when you report a concrete point at which you are stuck but they are, understandably, less eager to punch in all the texts from your screen shot.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat You're absolutely right, I was rather hoping that someone already has something similar saved somewhere.

Comment: Related: https://ctan.org/topic/gantt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have some repetitive tasks, it is usually a good idea to define styles and pics. This answer has a pic for the interval bar, the appearance of which is fully controlled by pgf keys. For instance,

```
\path[thick] 
    (0,0) pic[intervals/.cd,step=2cm]{intervals={1,2,3,4,\dots,12,1}};
```

leads to the upper interval bar. These pics make the code look long if you only use them once or twice, but they do pay off if you use them more often than that. I did not know to which extent the whole diagram is repetitive. If so, you may define a pic for it, too. Anyway, I leave this as an exercise.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\tikzset{pics/intervals/.style={code={%
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/intervals/##1}}%
\foreach \XX [count=\YY] in {#1}
{\draw (\YY*\pv{step},\pv{tick length}/2) -- (\YY*\pv{step},-\pv{tick length}/2);
\path (\YY*\pv{step}-0.5*\pv{step},-\pv{tick length}/2)
node[below]{\XX};
\xdef\tmpintcnt{\YY}}
\draw (0,\pv{tick length}/2) -- (0,-\pv{tick length}/2);
\draw[intervals/arrow] (0,0) -- (\tmpintcnt*\pv{step}+\pv{overshoot},0);
}},
intervals/.cd,tick length/.initial=3mm,step/.initial=1cm,tick/.style={},
arrow/.style={-stealth},overshoot/.initial=5mm,
/tikz/.cd,math node/.style={execute at begin node=$,execute at end node=$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=upper]
  \path[thick] 
    (0,0) pic[intervals/.cd,step=2cm]{intervals={1,2,3,4,\dots,12,1}}
    (0,-2) pic[intervals/.cd,step=5mm]{intervals={1,...,15}};
  % upper rectangles    
  \draw[fill=gray!40] (0,0) rectangle (4,1) node[midway]{frozen periods};
  \draw[fill=white] (4,0) rectangle (12,1) node[midway]{open periods};
  % lower rectangles    
  \draw[fill=gray!40] (0,-2) rectangle ++(1,1);
  \draw (1,-2) rectangle ++(5,1);
  % dashed arrows   
  \foreach \X[count=\Y] in {->,->,->} 
  {\draw[\X,dashed,thick] (2*\Y,0) -- (2*\Y,-1);}
  % annotations on the left 
  \draw[thick] (0,1) -- (0,-2.5) node[pos=1/7,left] {APP}
     node[pos=5/7,left] {MPS};
 \end{scope}     
 %
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=lower,yshift=-5cm]
  \path[thick] 
    (0,0) pic[intervals/.cd,step=2cm]{intervals={1,2,3,4,\dots,12,1}}
    (0,-2) pic[intervals/.cd,step=5mm]{intervals={1,...,15}};
  % upper rectangles    
  \draw[pattern=north west lines] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
  \draw[fill=gray!40] (2,0) rectangle (4,1);
  \draw[fill=white] (4,0) rectangle (14,1);
  % lower rectangles    
  \draw[pattern=north west lines] (0,-2)  rectangle ++(0.5,1);
  \draw[fill=gray!40] (0.5,-2) rectangle ++(1,1);
  \draw (1.5,-2) rectangle ++(5,1);
  % dashed arrows   
  \foreach \X[count=\Y] in {<-,->,->} % one arrow reversed
  {\draw[\X,dashed,thick] (2*\Y,0) -- (2*\Y,-1);}
  % annotations on the left 
  \draw[thick] (0,1) -- (0,-2.5) node[pos=1/7,left] {APP}
     node[pos=5/7,left] {MPS};
 \end{scope}     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Apart from the above-mentioned second pic you may use e.g. the `patterns.meta` library to customize the pattern, and so on.

Answer (score 5):

I propose a solution with `pstricks` – it uses LaTeX-like commands, which are an interface with the postscript language

```
\documentclass[border=6pt, svgnames]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit =1.8cm,arrowinset=0.12, dimen=inner}%
\noindent \begin{pspicture}(-0.7,-2.5)(7.5,1)
%% first axis
\uput{1em}[l](0,0.5){APP}
\foreach \i/\j in {0.5/1,1.5/2,2.5/3,3.5/4,4.5/{...},5.5/12,6.5/1} {\uput{2ex}[d](\i, 0){\small\j}}
\psframe[linestyle=none, fillstyle=vlines](0,0)(1,1)
\psframe[linestyle=none, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=Gainsboro](1,0)(2,1)
\psline(0,0)(0,1)(7,1)(7,0)\psline(1,0)(1,1)\psline(2,0)(2,1)
            \psaxes[arrows=->, yAxis=false, labels=none](0,0)(0,0)(7.3,0)
% second axis
\psframe[linestyle=none, fillstyle=vlines](0,-2)(0.25,-1)
\psframe[linestyle=none, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=Gainsboro](0.25,-2)(1,-1)
\uput{1em}[l](0,-1.5){MPS}
\psline(0, -2)(0,-1)(3.25,-1)(3.25,-2)\psline(0.25,-2)(0.25,-1)\psline(1,-2)(1,-1)
            \psaxes[arrows=->, yAxis=false, labels=none, dx=0.25](0,-2)(0,-2)(4,-2)
\multido{\n = 0.125 + 0.250,\i=1+1}{15}{\uput{2ex}[d](\n, -2){\small\i}}
\psset{linestyle=dashed, arrows=->}
\psline(1,-1)(1,0)\psline(2,0)(2,-1)\psline(3,0)(3,-1)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

After some fiddling around with `pgfgantt` I was able to recreate it there too... The look can certainly be improved, but it's not too bad. I thought I'd share it here:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{Rolling Horizon Planning}
\label{pic4}
\centering
\newganttlinktype{d1}{
    \ganttsetstartanchor{south}
    \ganttsetendanchor{on top=.2}
    \draw[/pgfgantt/link]
    (\xLeft, \yUpper) --
    (\xRight, \yLower);
}
\newganttlinktype{d2}{
    \ganttsetstartanchor{on bottom=1}
    \ganttsetendanchor{on top=.6}
    \draw[/pgfgantt/link]
    (\xLeft, \yUpper) --
    (\xRight, \yLower);
}
\newganttlinktype{d3}{
    \ganttsetstartanchor{on bottom=.25}
    \ganttsetendanchor{on top=1}
    \draw[/pgfgantt/link]
    (\xLeft, \yUpper) --
    (\xRight, \yLower);
}
\newganttlinktype{d4}{
    \ganttsetstartanchor{on bottom=0}
    \ganttsetendanchor{on top=.5}
    \draw[/pgfgantt/link]
    (\xLeft, \yUpper) --
    (\xRight, \yLower);
}
\newganttlinktype{d5}{
    \ganttsetstartanchor{on bottom=.2}
    \ganttsetendanchor{on top=.9}
    \draw[/pgfgantt/link]
    (\xLeft, \yUpper) --
    (\xRight, \yLower);
}
\newganttlinktype{d6}{
    \ganttsetstartanchor{south}
    \ganttsetendanchor{on top=.4}
    \draw[/pgfgantt/link]
    (\xLeft, \yUpper) --
    (\xRight, \yLower);
}
\newganttlinktype{d7}{
    \ganttsetstartanchor{on bottom=1}
    \ganttsetendanchor{on top=.8}
    \draw[/pgfgantt/link]
    (\xLeft, \yUpper) --
    (\xRight, \yLower);
}
\newganttlinktype{u1}{
    \ganttsetstartanchor{on bottom=0}
    \ganttsetendanchor{on top=0.1}
    \draw[/pgfgantt/link]
    (\xLeft, \yUpper) --
    (\xRight, \yLower);
}
\newganttlinktype{u2}{
    \ganttsetstartanchor{on bottom=0}
    \ganttsetendanchor{on top=0}
    \draw[/pgfgantt/link]
    (\xLeft, \yUpper) --
    (\xRight, \yLower);
}
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid, link/.style={line width=1pt}, link bulge=.58]{1}{28}
\gantttitle{Iteration 1}{28}\\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,4}{4}
\gantttitle{...}{4}
\gantttitlelist{12}{4}
\gantttitlelist{1}{4} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,16}{1} \\
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=lightgray, dashed}]{APP}{1}{8}
\ganttbar{}{9}{24}\\
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=lightgray, dashed}]{MPS}{1}{2}
\ganttbar{}{3}{12}\\
\gantttitle{Iteration 2}{28}\\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,4}{4}
\gantttitle{...}{4}
\gantttitlelist{12}{4}
\gantttitlelist{1}{4} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,16}{1} \\
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=gray}]{APP}{1}{4}
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=lightgray, dashed}]{}{5}{8}
\ganttbar{}{9}{28}\\
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=gray}]{MPS}{1}{1}
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=lightgray, dashed}]{}{2}{3}
\ganttbar{}{4}{13}\\
\gantttitle{Iteration 3}{28}\\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,4}{4}
\gantttitle{...}{4}
\gantttitlelist{12}{4}
\gantttitlelist{1}{4} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,16}{1} \\
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=gray}]{APP}{1}{4}
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=lightgray, dashed}]{}{5}{12}
\ganttbar{}{13}{28}\\
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=gray}]{MPS}{1}{2}
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=lightgray, dashed}]{}{3}{4}
\ganttbar{}{5}{14}
\ganttlink[link type=d1, link/.style={->, red}]{elem0}{elem3}
\ganttlink[link type=d2, link/.style={->, red}]{elem0}{elem3}
\ganttlink[link type=d3, link/.style={->, red}]{elem1}{elem3}
\ganttlink[link type=u1, link/.style={<-, dashed, gray}]{elem5}{elem9}
\ganttlink[link type=d4, link/.style={->, red}]{elem6}{elem9}
\ganttlink[link type=d5, link/.style={->, red}]{elem6}{elem9}
\ganttlink[link type=u2, link/.style={<-, dashed, gray}]{elem11}{elem15}
\ganttlink[link type=d6, link/.style={->, red}]{elem11}{elem15}
\ganttlink[link type=d7, link/.style={->, red}]{elem11}{elem15}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{figure}
```

[image]